# How to properly show the data that edited by Redactor JQuery editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I  am using [Redactor](http://redactorjs.com/) for editing in my page, it works fine and cool. When I finish editing, I store the content in database. The question is when I fecth the content from database, how can I show it like it showed in Redactor? I found that the content contains some HTML format tags, like `<p>, <b>,` and so on. Weather I escape it or not, it print string likes `<p>blahblah</p>` in browser.

How can I show the content like it showed in Redactor when I edited?

Thank you.

Comment: What tags aren't showing correctly?

Comment: @Jleagle All tags. When I fetch the content from database, say `content`. should I put it into a `div`? Like <div>{{content}}</div>.

Comment: Look in your database and see how it's saved. Your form validation might be stripping all HTML elements

Comment: Do you want to display the content formatted or raw code?

Comment: @CyberJunkie I want to display the formatted content.

Comment: @stevenYANG your question isn't very clear. In your browser you're seeing the actual tags? `<p>, <b>, etc` or plain text that isn't formatted?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow or deny tags:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    allowedTags: ['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'pre']
});
```

and

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    deniedTags: ['blockquote', 'div']
});
```

Setup what you like redactor to keep or what you would like to strip from the editable content.

> Source: http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/